# Creating 2d latice in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a 2d periodic structure in Matlab with a constant number of points in each direction (say b) so there are b*b points in the square. if we call the total size of lattice box equal to L, how can I do that? For short b's, I can do it by hand. For example for b= 2 and l=25:

```
x = [6.25;18.75;18.75;6.25]; 
y = [6.25;18.75;6.25;18.75];
```

But how can I do it for large b's and different l's?

Based on answers, I think the question is not clear. So I add another example:
I want to choose 3^2 points in a squre with length equal to 27. it is shown in below picture:

[image]

In this case, the answer is:

```
x= [4.5;13.5;22.5;4.5;13.5;22.5;4.5;13.5;22.5] %x component of position of points
y= [22.5;22.5;22.5;13.5;13.5;13.5;4.5;4.5;4.5] %y component of position of points
```

Comment: I don't understand how `x` and `y` are calculated. What is the closed form formula?

Comment: I choose them so that |x_2-x_1|= |l+x_1-x_2| and the same for y... @rayryeng

Comment: I want to create a 2d periodic structure @rayryeng

Comment: are you looking for `meshgrid`?

Comment: No. I want to choose n^2 points in the square with length equal to L. @AnderBiguri

Comment: So you do, indeed, want a `meshgrid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, now I see what you want.

```
oneLattice = (l/(2*b) : l/b : l);
x = repmat(oneLattice, 1, b)'; % Make a column vector.
y = repmat(oneLattice, b, 1); % will be a matrix. You can use it the same as x - linear indexing.
y = y(:); % To make it in a single column.
```

Old version:

I presume step was chosen to have same distance between all points with the first point and last one symmetric, which is sensible and quite usual. And it seems x has mirrored boundary condition, while for y it is periodic (which you should tell next time).

```
oneLattice = (l/(2*b) : l/b : l)';
x = [oneLattice; oneLattice(end:-1:1)];
y = [oneLattice; oneLattice];
```

Brief explanation: step between points is l/b to have b points on lattice l. Anything for the first point between 0+epsilon and l/b would work. (To start with 0, you would need end condition l-epsilon to not have b+1 points). To have it centered - as away from edge as the last point, you should obviously put it in the middle, so l/b/2.

Just a side note, next time try to not use l as a variable. It is too similar to 1.

Comment: there is no mirror boundary conditon. I want to find position of sites in the lattice in 2d.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. I want b*b points in a square with length l.

Comment: @saranj Yeah well, I produced something that matches your sample output for x and y and is in the similar pattern. How am I supposed to know you require something else? Fix your question and I will consider fixing my answer.

Comment: @saranj Yeah, it is clearer you want matrix now, but what should be the sample output for b=2 and l=25? Simple A=x*y? Do `A=x*y';`. Maybe A = [0, 6.25, 18.75; 6.25, 1, 1; 18.25, 1, 1];? Then `A = zeros(b+1); A(2:end,1) = oneLattice; A(1, 2:end) = oneLattice; A(2:end,2:end)=1;` Or maybe A = [6.25, 18.25; 18.25, 6.25]? In this case `for i = 1:b A(i, :) = y(i:i+b-1);`

Comment: The values of b could just take Square numbers